# How does different spacing affect the unary operator?

Tags: java, unary-operator

Can anyone explain me how different spacing affects the unary operator?

```
int i = 1;
int j = i+ + +i; // this will print j=2
int k = i++ +i; // this will print k=3
int l = i+++i; // this will print l=3
int m = i++++i; // compile time error
```

.

Comment: just for curiosity, if you are executing all these statements in a sequence, then for int l = i+++i;, the initial value of i would be 2 because it has already been incremented in the previous step, so it might affect the result as well.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First, let's separate this into three separate cases which can't interact:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i+ + +i); // 2

int j = 1;
System.out.println(j++ +j); // 3

int k = 1;
System.out.println(k+++k); // 3
```

Now let's rewrite them using brackets:

```
int i = 1;
System.out.println(i + (+(+i)));

int j = 1;
System.out.println((j++) + j);

int k = 1;
System.out.println((k++) + k);
```

### First operation

Here we *can't* be using the prefix or postfix ++ operators, as we don't have a token of `++` anywhere. Instead, we have a binary + operator and two unary + operators.

### Second operation

This one's simple: it's pretty much as it reads, a postfix ++ operator followed by a binary + operator (not the unary + operator that `+j` might otherwise imply).

### Third operation

The final line is parsed as `(k++) + k` rather than `k + (++k)`. Both will actually give the same answer in *this* situation, but we can prove which is which by using two different variables instead:

```
int k1 = 1;
int k2 = 1;
System.out.println(k1+++k2); // Prints 2
System.out.println(k1); // Prints 2
System.out.println(k2); // Prints 1
```

As you can see, it's `k1` that's been incremented rather than `k2`.

The reason that `k+++k` is parsed as tokens of `k`, `++`, `+`, `k` is due to [section 3.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2), which includes:

> The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the result does not ultimately make a correct program while another lexical translation would.

### Fourth operation (compile failure)

The same "longest possible translation" rule parses `i++++i` as `i`, `++` ,`++`, `i` which isn't a valid expression (because the result of the `++` operation is a value, not a variable).

Comment: I am not certain that operator precedence is the reason behind the interpretation of the third line. I suspect that it is a consequence of the maximal munch rule implemented in the lexer: when it sees a sequence of characters, it tries to construct the longest token that it can. In case of a sequence of plus signs that would be a `++` token.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hmm. You could be right. I think I'll change it to just say what I definitely know (the actual interpretation) rather than the explanation :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, Is the third operation `(k++) + k` is because of _operator precedence_ or because of _maximum munch rule_ ?

Comment: @Zeeshan: I haven't been able to work that out for sure. Looks like I accidentally left a reference to precedence in there. I'll remove that now.

Comment: @Zeeshan `k+++k` was parsed as `k++ + k` because of  maximum munch rule. But the expression `k++ + k` (but it doesn't say itself which operator evaluate first) is equivalent to `(k++) + k` because of precedence rules.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Operands are *always* evaluated left-to-right. That's not a matter of precedence. It's not clear where you believe the precedence part comes in, bearing in mind the maximum munch rule (which I still haven't found a reference for in the JLS, unfortunately) splits it into `k++ + k`. There's no room for precedence to change what that means - there's a unary postfix-++ opreator and a binary + operator... there's no grouping which precedence could affect, as far as I ca ntell.

Comment: @JonSkeet,  [Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2)

Comment: Note that the maximum munch rule also causes the fourth line to fail to parse. It is interpreted as the sequence of tokens: i, ++, ++, i, which is not a valid expression.

Comment: @JonSkeet, is the outcome the same in C#?

Comment: @Ian: I haven't checked, but I expect so.

Answer (score 13):

`+` is an operator, and `++` is an operator, but `+ +` is not - `+ +` is interpreted as two `+`s, not one `++`. So the space forces your code to be interpreted differently.

`+` is both a binary operator which adds two numbers and a unary operator which does not change a number (it exists only for consistency with the unary `-` operator).

If we use `add` instead of binary `+`, `no-change` instead of unary `+`, and `increment` instead of `++` then it might be more clear.

`int j=i+ + +i` becomes `int j = i add no-change no-change i;`.
`int k=i++ +i;` becomes `int k=i increment add i;`.
I suspect `int k = i+++i;` also becomes `int k = i increment add i;` but I have not checked this with the language specification.

Comment: Importantly, `+ +` is interpreted as a binary `+` operator followed by a unary `+` operator (I believe). That makes your "add add add" interpretation less helpful than "add unary-plus unary-plus". So `int j = i+ + +i` is equivalent to `int j = i + (+(+i));

Comment: More importantly, please explain what's the deal with three pluses in a row.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Just got confused by writing confusing code. Studying bizarre edge cases can be useful to get an understanding of how things really work. ;)